# IBM worklight WL.JSONStore.QueryPart(). Jsonstore error

Tags: javascript, html, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

when i use an advance search, it shows that WL.JSONStore.QueryPart(). is not a function and it is not recognized as something existent, is it deprecated or i need to use it differently?

```
var queryPart1 = WL.JSONStore.QueryPart().like('category', 'abc')
var queryPart2 = WL.JSONStore.QueryPart().like('category', 'xyz');

  WL.JSONStore.get('Categories').advancedFind([queryPart1,queryPart2])

   .then(function(results){

                     })

.fail(function(errorObject) {
                        alert("fail" + errorObject); 
                          });
```

Comment: What version of IBM Worklight are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 6.1.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parts and advancedFind are only supported on version 6.2 and above.